# Biblatex cite and footcite: lastname, shorttile, in: journaltitle

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I need to change the biblatex cite and footcite command such that it prints the lastname, the shorttitle and also the journaltitle. Getting the lastname and shorttitle worked out of the box, but for the journaltitle the cite and/or footcite command has to be changed, I assume. 
Here is how far I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
style=authortitle-dw,
journalnumber=date,
idembibformat=dash,
sorting=nyt,
maxcitenames=1,
maxbibnames=2,
url=false, 
doi=false
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Angenendt~\footcite{angenendt} has a shorttitle.
  And Augustine \footcite{augustine} also has a shorttitle.
  Kullback~\footcite{kullback} is a book.
  Bertram~\footcite{bertram} also has a short title, only two words long.
  Doody~\footcite{doody} does not have a shorttile.
  Kullback~\footcite{kullback} is a book.
  Sometimes citatations are in footnotes.\footnote{so i can have more text and so on like \cite{bertram}}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant macro is `cite:title`. We add the block

```
     \ifentrytype{article}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{in:}%
        \printfield{journaltitle}}
       {}%
```

to print the `journaltitle` for `@article` entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  style=authortitle-dw,
  journalnumber=date,
  idembibformat=dash,
  sorting=nyt,
  maxcitenames=1,
  maxbibnames=2,
  url=false, 
  doi=false
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifsingletitle
    {\setunit{}}% Löschen des \nametitledelim, falls kein Titel ausgegeben wird
    {\ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifentrytype{review}}
      and
      not test {\iffieldundef{xref}}
    }
      {\printtext[review]{\bbx@review{\thefield{xref}}}}
      {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
     \ifentrytype{article}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{in:}%
        \printfield{journaltitle}}
       {}%
     \ifbool{cbx:addyear}
        {\iffieldundef{year}
           {}
           {\titleyeardelim%
            \parentext{\printfield{year}}}}
        {}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Angenendt~\footcite{angenendt} has a shorttitle.
  And Augustine \footcite{augustine} also has a shorttitle.
  Kullback~\footcite{kullback} is a book.
  Bertram~\footcite{bertram} also has a short title, only two words long.
  Doody~\footcite{doody} does not have a shorttile.
  Kullback~\footcite{kullback} is a book.
  Sometimes citatations are in footnotes.\footnote{so i can have more text and so on like \cite{bertram}}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Fn 1 Angenendt: In Honore Salvatoris, in: Revue d’Histoire Ecclésiastique.//Fn. 2 Augustine: Heterogeneous catalysis.]